# Uploading images to database

Tags: database, image, yii

I am quite new to Yii and I'm having some problems.

I'm trying to upload images to the database following the [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/95/saving-files-to-a-blob-field-in-the-database/).
However, I can't seem to make it work. It always sees that there is nothing being uploaded.

Here is my code for the model:

```
public $uploadedFile;

/**
* Saves the name, size, type and data of the uploaded file
*/
public function beforeSave()
{
    if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'uploadedFile'))
    {
        $this->image_name=$file->name;
        $this->image_type=$file->type;
        $this->image_size=$file->size;
        $this->image=file_get_contents($file->tempName);
    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Controller for Create:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Subdivision;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Subdivision']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Subdivision'];
        $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'image');

        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->subdivision));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and my form code:

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    </div>
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Next line is not needed in your `actionCreate`:

```
$model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'image'); // remove it
```

Your POST processing should look like

```
if (isset($_POST['Subdivision']))
{
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Subdivision'];
    if ($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->subdivision));
}
```

Also make sure your `image` field in database has corresponding type of BLOB to store binary data.

---

### Edit, working sample

**Model** (only important parts left)

```
public $uploadedFile;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('uploadedFile', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
        array('image_name,image_type,image_size,image', 'safe')
    );
}

public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'uploadedFile'))
    {
        $this->image_name = $file->name;
        $this->image_type = $file->type;
        $this->image_size = $file->size;
        $this->image = file_get_contents($file->tempName);
    }

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new User(); /* I called my model User in your case it's Subdivision */

    if (isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');

        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
    }

    $this->render('index', array(
        'model' => $model
    ));
}
```

**View**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
)); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'uploadedFile'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'uploadedFile'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'uploadedFile'); ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: yes image field is of BLOB type but the problem still persists.

It still says "Image cannot be blank" when saving.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you defined `'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')` inside your `$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array( ... )` ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes, I've also defined that in my form but it still can't seem

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes I've also defined htmlOptions in my _form and it still cannot upload anything.

Comment: How do you define your rules in the model?

Comment: here are the code for my rules:

`array('image_size', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),`
`array('subdivision, division', 'length', 'max'=>30),`
`array('image_name, image_type', 'length', 'max'=>50),`
`array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, png, gif'),`
`array('subdivision, division, image_name, image_size, image_type, image','safe', 'on'=>'search'),`

Comment: Ok. Just remove the following rules as you don't need them: `array('image_size', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
array('image_name, image_type', 'length', 'max' => 50),
array('image', 'file', 'types' => 'jpg, png, gif')`. The only rule you need is `array('uploadedFile', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png')`

Comment: i tried your suggestion and it still can't upload properly..
i'm at a loss here..

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what's wrong in your case. I followed the wiki and everything works just fine. I've updated my answer with my code. Compare it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

**Code for saving Image in dataBase**

**Model**

```
public function beforeSave()
        {
            if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'uploadedFile'))
            {
                $this->image=$file->name;
                $this->image=$file->type;
                $this->image=$file->size;
                $this->image=file_get_contents($file->tempName);
            }

        return parent::beforeSave();
        }
```

**Form**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
)); ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'uploadedFile'); ?>
    </div>
```

Add these to your rules in Model

```
return array( array('uploadedFile', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
                    array('image_name,image_type,image_size,image', 'safe'));
```

*Please remove image- required in rules.*